# Please provide a valid cache path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.2

Acabei de fazer um `git clone` (copiar)  uma aplicação Laravel recém feita na empresa onde eu trabalho.

Rodei o `composer update` e `artisan key generate` para fazer as configurações iniciais, bem como editei o arquivo `.env` para poder configurar o banco de dados.

Tudo está perfeitamente configurado, porém aparece uma Exception ao executar a aplicação:

> Please provide a valid cache path

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme dito [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483837/please-provide-a-valid-cache-path), experimenta criar os diretórios, em **storage/framework**:

- sessions
- views
- cache

Talvez estejam em falta.

[Esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931728/laravel-error-please-provide-a-valid-cache-path), ainda acresencenta que podes executar o comando:

```
composer install
```

Comment: O `composer install` já foi rodado. Era realmente apenas problema da falta das pastas.

Comment: Ótimo @WallaceMaxters, ainda bem que está resolvido, esses problemas são realmente chatos porque uma pessoa não faz ideia do que possa ser. Um viva ao Google nestes casos

Comment: Não usem sudo para instalar as dependências do composer, pode (e possivelmente irá) criar problemas de permissão. Ao invés, é preferível corrigir as permissões do utilizador para puder criar directórios e assim deixar a framework criar as pastas necessárias com o utilizador corrente.

Comment: @Gui, tens toda a razão, editei a resposta